# Bash : Shell script delete files matching all the passed arguments?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

This is an assignment question, so I'm not directly looking for an answer or the script. So in one of my questions, I'm asked that I should delete the files containing **any** of the passed command line arguments.
Here is the script snippet for that

```
#!/bin/sh

#some more stuff here

for args in "$@"; do
    if  [ $#  != 0 ]; then
        grep -l $args * | while read theFile; 
        do
            if [ -f "$theFile" ] ; then
                rm "$theFile"
                echo "$theFile is deleted with $args match"
            else
                echo "$theFile not deleted"
                exit 2
            fi
        done #end of while loop
    else 
        echo "No match found with $args"
        exit 1
    fi
    done
echo "DONE"
exit 0
```

Now, I'd like to know *how I would write the script so that it would delete the files that have **ALL** the arguments*? I understand that I need to check if each file has the arguments passed with either a for loop, but I'm not sure how I'd be writing it. Any inputs will be appreciated.

I'm using cloud9 to practice, if that info is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You're now looping over the keywords (`for arg in..`), and then, for each keyword, checking  which files contain that keyword (`grep -l $arg *`).

To check for files that have all keywords you could invert that, and loop over all files (`for f in *`), and then loop over the keywords (`for arg in "$@"`), checking if the file contains them (`grep -qe "$arg" "$f"`) only removing if all of them match.

That's a bit of a brute force, as you'd execute `grep` *n***m* times, for *n* files and *m* keywords. The alternative would be to run `grep -l` for the first keyword, then `grep -l` for the second keyword, giving `grep` the list of files returned by the last grep, etc. You'd probably want to save the list of files in an array in every step.

---

As a side note, this doesn't make any sense:

```
for args in "$@"; do
    if  [ $#  != 0 ];
```

You're checking the number arguments inside a loop that runs once for each argument. `$#` is zero exactly when there are no arguments, but then `"$@"` doesn't contain anything either, and the loop will not run.

Here:

```
grep -l $args * | while read theFile;
```

You should probably quote `$args`, and you may also want to take a look at [BashFAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for info about using `while read` ...

In short, you probably want

```
grep -l "$args" * | while IFS= read -r theFile; do
```